# CSS to make this responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make this responsive but the problem is when I reduce my window size it goes out of the screen

```
<h5>User Stories</h5><div class="stories-list d-flex "><div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/578e883ef475d1232ce59936563bbe4e/5B726BC1/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ff89a52784b070742b3a20a8e66fee65/5B726D26/t51.12442-15/e35/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7f73c9a2e9e023cb992050eed84c800b/5B729C5D/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7876d21a14741ec0d4d33e459edd77b/5B7368FA/t51.12442-15/e35/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/578e883ef475d1232ce59936563bbe4e/5B726BC1/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ff89a52784b070742b3a20a8e66fee65/5B726D26/t51.12442-15/e35/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7f73c9a2e9e023cb992050eed84c800b/5B729C5D/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7876d21a14741ec0d4d33e459edd77b/5B7368FA/t51.12442-15/e35/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/578e883ef475d1232ce59936563bbe4e/5B726BC1/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ff89a52784b070742b3a20a8e66fee65/5B726D26/t51.12442-15/e35/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7f73c9a2e9e023cb992050eed84c800b/5B729C5D/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7876d21a14741ec0d4d33e459edd77b/5B7368FA/t51.12442-15/e35/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>
</div>
```

---

```
    .stories-list>div {
    height: 220px;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div {
    display: block;
}
.flex-column {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.position-relative {
    position: relative;
}
.stories-list>div>img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.d-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
.story-hover, .story-hover>p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.story-hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.stories-list>div:hover>.story-hover {
    display: block;
}
.story-hover>p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBOvQm

Here is what I am trying to achieve

[On PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCIwE.png)

[Automatically changes it to a new line to fit the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2AB6.jpg)

So this is what I wanted to make out of the image on the codepen part. to make it in a new line to make it responsive

Answer (score 1):

Is this what u want?

Add `flex-wrap:wrap;` to

```
.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

This property will automatically push the items on next line when there is no enough space.

```css
.stories-list>div {
  height: 220px;
  width: 125px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.flex-column {
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.stories-list>div>img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.d-flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.story-hover,
.story-hover>p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.story-hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.stories-list>div:hover>.story-hover {
  display: block;
}

.story-hover>p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h5>User Stories</h5>
<div class="stories-list d-flex ">
  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/578e883ef475d1232ce59936563bbe4e/5B726BC1/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" alt="story">
    <!---->
    <a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ff89a52784b070742b3a20a8e66fee65/5B726D26/t51.12442-15/e35/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover">
      <p>Download</p>
    </a>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7f73c9a2e9e023cb992050eed84c800b/5B729C5D/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" alt="story">
    <!---->
    <a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7876d21a14741ec0d4d33e459edd77b/5B7368FA/t51.12442-15/e35/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover">
      <p>Download</p>
    </a>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/578e883ef475d1232ce59936563bbe4e/5B726BC1/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" alt="story">
    <!---->
    <a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ff89a52784b070742b3a20a8e66fee65/5B726D26/t51.12442-15/e35/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover">
      <p>Download</p>
    </a>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7f73c9a2e9e023cb992050eed84c800b/5B729C5D/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" alt="story">
    <!---->
    <a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7876d21a14741ec0d4d33e459edd77b/5B7368FA/t51.12442-15/e35/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover">
      <p>Download</p>
    </a>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/578e883ef475d1232ce59936563bbe4e/5B726BC1/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" alt="story">
    <!---->
    <a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ff89a52784b070742b3a20a8e66fee65/5B726D26/t51.12442-15/e35/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover">
      <p>Download</p>
    </a>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7f73c9a2e9e023cb992050eed84c800b/5B729C5D/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" alt="story">
    <!---->
    <a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7876d21a14741ec0d4d33e459edd77b/5B7368FA/t51.12442-15/e35/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover">
      <p>Download</p>
    </a>
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <!---->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @jackwhacky ,if this answer helped u then please accept it

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to have as many of the `<div>` elements as possible to fit on a single line, but reflow them to multiple lines if they don't fit, the easiest way to do this might be to give them the `display: inline-block` style (the same as the default for an `<img>` element, i.e., it renders somewhat as a big text character).

(NOTE I deleted the 'flex' stuff, a simple reflow works perfectly well without it).

```css
.stories-list>div {
    height: 220px;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div {
    display: block;
}
.position-relative {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.stories-list>div>img {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.story-hover, .story-hover>p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.story-hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.stories-list>div:hover>.story-hover {
    display: block;
}
.story-hover>p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #fff;
    bottom: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h5>User Stories</h5><div class="stories-list"><div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/578e883ef475d1232ce59936563bbe4e/5B726BC1/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ff89a52784b070742b3a20a8e66fee65/5B726D26/t51.12442-15/e35/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7f73c9a2e9e023cb992050eed84c800b/5B729C5D/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7876d21a14741ec0d4d33e459edd77b/5B7368FA/t51.12442-15/e35/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/578e883ef475d1232ce59936563bbe4e/5B726BC1/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ff89a52784b070742b3a20a8e66fee65/5B726D26/t51.12442-15/e35/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7f73c9a2e9e023cb992050eed84c800b/5B729C5D/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7876d21a14741ec0d4d33e459edd77b/5B7368FA/t51.12442-15/e35/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/578e883ef475d1232ce59936563bbe4e/5B726BC1/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/ff89a52784b070742b3a20a8e66fee65/5B726D26/t51.12442-15/e35/38035134_221249845233474_6747640763024146432_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>


  <div class="position-relative"><img src="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/7f73c9a2e9e023cb992050eed84c800b/5B729C5D/t51.12442-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" alt="story"><!----><a href="https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/b7876d21a14741ec0d4d33e459edd77b/5B7368FA/t51.12442-15/e35/37970915_275334373066916_3183150178899066880_n.jpg" target="_self" class="story-hover"><p>Download</p></a><!----><!----><!----></div>
</div>
```